# Распределение файлов внутри проекта C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Не пойму в чем проблема. Создал папку внутри проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перекинул туда несколько классов, класс main к примеру теперь их не видит. Даже внутри директории они друг друга не видят.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имя проекта MSU, пытаюсь сделать так:

```
using MSU.LoginDir;
```

Ругается на несуществующую директорию. Что не так?
Заглушка тоже почему-то предлагает имя директории, которой нету в проекте, есть класс с таким именем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неймспейсы поправили после перемещения файлов?

Comment: @tym32167 забыл :( спасибо Вам огромное за быстрый ответ.